# How to fetch records from array1 which is not available in array2 based for specific category by applying where clause

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have two `array object` with data. `array1` has 112 records where `orgName ="ABC"`  and `array2` has 102 records again `orgName ="ABC"`. I want to get extra 10 records in `arrayNew` from `array1` which are not there in array2.

I tried this but it gives me total records irrespective to `orgName`, how can I apply `where` or `filter` for `orgName`.

```
let arrayNew = array1.filter( ( el ) => !array2.includes( el ) );
```

How can I do that? also, can anyone let me know what this is called `intersection`?

This is how my data looks

```
    array1=
    {
        "orgId": 101,
        "orgGN": "ABC",
        "dId": 494,
        "name": "Test1",
    },
        {
        "orgId": 102,
        "orgGN": "ABC",
        "dId": 442,
        "name": "Test2",
    },
        {
        "orgId": 103,
        "orgGN": "ASR",
        "dId": 494,
        "name": "Test3",
    },

array2=
{
    "orgId": 101,
    "orgGN": "ABC",
    "dId": 494,
    "name": "Test1",
},
{
    "orgId": 105,
    "orgGN": "PDC",
    "dId": 420,
    "name": "Test5",
},
{
    "orgId": 106,
    "orgGN": "ASR",
    "dId": 44,
    "name": "Test6",
},
```

Expected OP

```
    {
    "orgId": 102,
    "orgGN": "ABC",
    "dId": 442,
    "name": "Test2",
},
```

Comment: Could you show us several items from array1 and matching items from array2?

Comment: Intersection of sets is the set that contains elements which presents in all initial sets.

Comment: @AlexanderSmirnov - Both of my array fields are same. You can say both object are same but different data.

Comment: I mean, is array1 looks like this ```const array1 = [{orgName:"ABC"}, {orgName: "..."}]```?

Comment: @AlexanderSmirnov - Both they have nearly 50k records JSON coming from server but yeah they should treat same as `const array1 = [{orgName:"ABC"}, {orgName: "..."}]` Each and every record has unique ID.

Comment: Then @Saar probably answers your question.

Comment: @AlexanderSmirnov Checking that.. One doubt in his answer.. He is picking array of orgName.. What difference does it make?

Comment: I would say: He takes all orgName-s from second array and filter out those array1 items which orgName-s included in array2 orgName-s list. Isn't it what you are looking for?

Comment: the source data and desired output will help you to get answer faster and better and to us to make a better answer

Comment: @AlexanderSmirnov - No, I have nearly 1k organization but only for ABC I want to get records which is not there in array2 but available in array1.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of the `orgId`s of `array2` and filter `array1` by the `orgName` field and needed value like so:

```js
array1 = [{
    "orgId": 101,
    "orgGN": "ABC",
    "dId": 494,
    "name": "Test1",
  },
  {
    "orgId": 102,
    "orgGN": "ABC",
    "dId": 442,
    "name": "Test2",
  },
  {
    "orgId": 103,
    "orgGN": "ASR",
    "dId": 494,
    "name": "Test3",
  }
];

const array2 = [{
    "orgId": 101,
    "orgGN": "ABC",
    "dId": 494,
    "name": "Test1",
  },
  {
    "orgId": 105,
    "orgGN": "PDC",
    "dId": 420,
    "name": "Test5",
  },
  {
    "orgId": 106,
    "orgGN": "ASR",
    "dId": 44,
    "name": "Test6",
  }
];

function intersection(array1, array2, field, value) {
  const array2OrgIds = array2.map(item => item.orgId);

  return  array1.filter((el) => !array2OrgNames.includes(el.orgId) && el[field] === value);
}

console.log(intersection(array1, array2, "orgGN", "ABC"));
```

Comment: I have only single orgName. ID will be unique for each records

Comment: so you want to compare by `orgName` and get the intersection of the object by this property?

Comment: I am expecting OP only 102, ABC. not ASR.

Comment: I edited my answer. let me know if that's what you mean

Answer (score 1):

It looks like we have composite key here such as `orgId` and `orgGN`. So it is possible to use `Map` collection to have `O(n)` time complexity with composite key while you are filtering your items:

```js
let array1 = [
{
    "orgId": 101,         "orgGN": "ABC",        "dId": 494,
    "name": "Test1",
},
{
    "orgId": 102,        "orgGN": "ABC",        "dId": 442, /* +++*/
    "name": "Test2",
},
{
    "orgId": 103,        "orgGN": "ASR",        "dId": 494,
    "name": "Test3",
}];

let array2 =
[{
    "orgId": 101,        "orgGN": "ABC",        "dId": 494,
    "name": "Test1",
},
{
    "orgId": 105,        "orgGN": "PDC",        "dId": 420,
    "name": "Test5",
},
{
    "orgId": 106,        "orgGN": "ASR",        "dId": 44,
    "name": "Test6",
}];

const uniqueItems = new Map(array2.map(s => [`${s.orgId}-${s.orgGN}` , s]));
const result = array1.filter(f=> !uniqueItems.get(`${f.orgId}-${f.orgGN}`) && f.orgGN == 'ABC');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Its not working.. uniqueItems  showing one record and filtered is 0.

Comment: I am getting 102 records not 10 records.

Comment: @R15 it looks like your actual data is not like the data you've posted.

Comment: I will post more accurate data and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the structure of your data but this will return a new array containing objects that are not in the array2 but are in array1 and their orgName is ABC:

```js
const array1 = [
    {
        orgId: 101,
        orgGN: "ABC",
        dId: 494,
        name: "Test1",
    },
    {
        orgId: 102,
        orgGN: "ABC",
        dId: 442,
        name: "Test2",
    },
    {
        orgId: 110,
        orgGN: "ABC",
        dId: 596,
        name: "Test10",
    },
    {
        orgId: 103,
        orgGN: "ASR",
        dId: 494,
        name: "Test3",
    },
];

const array2 = [
    {
        orgId: 101,
        orgGN: "ABC",
        dId: 494,
        name: "Test1",
    },
    {
        orgId: 105,
        orgGN: "PDC",
        dId: 420,
        name: "Test5",
    },
    {
        orgId: 106,
        orgGN: "ASR",
        dId: 44,
        name: "Test6",
    },
];

const objArrayDiff = (array1, array2, fieldName, fieldValue) => {
    return array1
        .filter((item) => item[fieldName] === fieldValue)
        .filter(
            (item) =>
                !array2
                    .filter((item) => item[fieldName] === fieldValue)
                    .some((array2Item) => array2Item.orgId === item.orgId)
        );
};

console.log(objArrayDiff(array1, array2, "orgGN", "ABC"));
```